# What is the AdobeAAMDetect plugin and how can I uninstall it?

Tags: uninstall, plugins

I did not ever remember installing this plugin by my choice or knowledge but it is in my browser plugins list.

[image]

What is it and can I uninstall it?

Comment: Which browser is this on?

Comment: I recently downgraded from the pirated version of Adobe products to the paid version and found crap like this on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what it is but I've uninstalled Adobe Creative Cloud with the [Adobe Creative Cloud Cleaner](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/cc-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html) tool:

[image]

...and deleted Adobe Application Manager:

[image]

Notice the folder, Adobe Application Manager and the link to Adobe Application Manager. These are both located under Applications > Utilities.

I restarted and it does not appear to be in the list of plugins anymore.

[image]

FYI I did not go into Firefox and remove it through the addons panel.

One thing to note is that I was not able to uninstall an application through the Adobe Creative Cloud Cleaner Tool once Adobe Application Manager was uninstalled:

[image]

I also was not able to uninstall applications listed in Applications > Utilities or use any of the red badge uninstallers in the Application directories themselves:

[image]

They display the same alert above.

However I am able to go into Applications and select the Adobe Dreamweaver CC folder and drag and drop it into the trash can.

I'd rather do that than have a plugin installed and running without my knowledge. It also contains the file [AdobeIPCBroker](https://forums.adobe.com/message/7876301#7876301) which was sending data to Adobe and running as a service in the background.

Comment: Update: I uninstalled it and now a few existing applications pop up an alert saying it is not installed. It warns that I will not get update notifications without it installed. I'll try and post a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

#### What is the AdobeAAMDetect plugin

It's part of the Adobe Application Manager and should not be uninstalled (You may cause the perpetual licensing or subscription to stop working, and you will not recieve updates).

> If you are using most Adobe products then AAM is installed and is required for the product to run correctly. AAM is used for Creative Cloud, and is also used for perpetual licensing (when you enter a serial number). AAM also handles updating your installed products.

...

> So please do not try and remove AAM from your system if you are using Adobe products. You may cause the perpetual licensing or subscription to stop working, and you will not recieve updates.

...

> Adobe application manager  is core application for all Adobe Creative Suite Products and is required for download, deployment, provisioning and updater functionality. Removing Adobe Application Manager from your machine may result in incorrect functioning of your product like Photoshop elements and Premier Elements in your case.  So my recommendation would be not to remove Adobe Application Manager from your machine.

Source [Completely uninstall Adobe Application Manager](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1070249)

---

#### But I want to uninstall it anyway ...

> You will need to get the [Adobe Creative Cloud Cleaner Tool](http://www.adobe.com/support/contact/cscleanertool.html).
>
> 1. Launch the Adobe Cleaner tool and in the top right drop-down select Creative Cloud.
> 2. In the list select "Creative Cloud Installer" and then click the button labelled "Cleanup selected".
> 3. The Adobe Application Manager will be removed from your computer.
>
>    [image]

Source [Completely uninstall Adobe Application Manager](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1070249)

Comment: Thank you! I was reading about this in another article. This is very clear. I had a different set of options and so I've posted an additional answer as well.

Comment: Somehow this answer does not make sense to me, the answer might be old etc, but to me "AdobeAAMDetect" seems to be a plugin for Safari. I could disable it by Safari > Preferences > Websites, and uncheck it from the list on the left... No need to uninstall anything.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is quite a difference between Adobe AAM and the AdobeAAMDetect.plugin.

The plugin? No idea what it does but Adobe is incredibly invasive now and there's no good reason of any kind why they install a system wide plugin. I've been trying for a few years to find a clear cut answer, literature, anything on what exactly this unwanted plugin is needed for.